# How to submit form using JavaScript and redirect to a URL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

How to submit form using JavaScript and redirect to a URL ?

```
<form name="f1" method="get" action="aaa.php">
    name : <input type="text" name="value_1" value=""/><br>
    age: <input type="text" name="value_2" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
```

please see image in this link:

http://image.ohozaa.com/i/4d0/zCzQIH.jpg

after press submit button , i want to redirect page to `www.example.com/aaa/robert/21`

How can i do that ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Maybe googled something? I bet this question has been asked a lot before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with html code

```
<form name="f1" method="get" action="aaa.php">
name : <input type="text" id="value_1" name="value_1" value=""/><br>
age: <input type="text" id="value_2" name="value_2" value=""/>
<input type="button" name="submit" onclick="checkredirect()" value="send"/>
```

And javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkredirect(){
    var value_1 = $('#value_1').val();
    var value_2 =  $('#value_2').val();
    window.location = 'http://www.example.com/'+value_1+'/'+value_2;
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Don't forget to add jQuery library

Comment: Add this to above javascrip and change button submit -> type="button"<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: ! not work, `www.example.com/aaa.php?value_1=robert&value_2=21&submit=send`

Comment: change to <input type="button" name="submit" onclick="checkredirect()" value="send"/>

Comment: Don't use onclick in the HTML, please, it is evil ;-)
Also, why change the window.location if the submit does it natively ? Just changing the `action` attribute value should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

set header in php file

```
$dynamic = $_GET['value_1'];
$id =$_GET['value_2'];
header('location:www.example.com/aaa/'.$dynamic.'/'.$id);
```

Comment: but `robet` and `21` is dynamic data.

Comment: set variable instead of robert and 21,check this edit

Comment: i mean `robert` and `21` are from form input.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function on click button

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
```

Comment: This literally does nothing.

Comment: Set action action="www.example.com/aaa/robert/21" this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

HTML:

```
<form id="f1" class="js-redirect" method="get" action="aaa.php">
    name : <input type="text" name="value_1" id="value_1" value=""/><br>
    age: <input type="text" name="value_2" id="value_2" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
```

N.B.: `name` attribute in `form` tags is deprecated, use `id` attribute. `Input`, `select` and `textarea` tags should have `id`s as well.

JS:

```
$('.js-redirect').on('submit', function() {
    var newUrl = this.action.replace('.php', '/' + $('#value_1').val() + '/' + $('#value_2').val());
    this.action = newUrl;
})
```