# Form submit to get clean url

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I don't know if I asked it right. I am a beginner.
I am building a website where items can be searched. There is a form in the website and the value is searched using php get method. And the url after form submit is something like this.

example.com/?q=item

I modified the htaccess file so that I can use example.com/item/ to get the same result, Which works.

What I need to do is redirect to example.com/item/ after user submits the form . How can I achieve this? Should I use javascript or php or which is better?

Comment: For displaying items it's (in my opinion) nicer to have an url like example.com/item/, but for a search form, why not just use the query string? That is pretty much the prime example of what you SHOULD use it for... You also prevent search engines from seeing search pages as actual pages, and it allows you to expend your search options.

Comment: Actually I need search engines to see this. I need to create something like this. [dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/good/](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/good/)

Comment: Ah that makes sense then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not both. Javascript for users who have it enabled. PHP as a fallback for those that don't.

**PHP**

```
if (!empty($_GET['q']))
{
    $redirecturl = $domainname . "/search/" . $_GET['q'];
    $redirecturl = str_replace(" ", "-", $redirecturl);
    header('Location: ' . $redirecturl, true, 303);
    die();
}
```

**Javascript**

See: [How to submit form using JavaScript and redirect to a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25989499/how-to-submit-form-using-javascript-and-redirect-to-a-url?rq=1)

Comment: The php code created a loop and the url was like example.com/example.com/search/example.com/search/......./item. How can I prevent this?